# Cannot access the console in Raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc, terminal

I cannot access to the console from the UI. I just want to setup my wifi card from console. I've tried with Shutdown or reboot and esc without success. I haven't an ethernet router port.

Is there anything more?

Comment: What OS are you using?  You didn't tag it.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's a XBMC. I've tried with ctrl+alt+fn and nothing.

Answer (score 6):

With Raspbmc, exit XBMC from the shutdown menu (choose exit, not shutdown). At the blue screen press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and you will be greeted with a login prompt.  The default username is "pi", the default password is "raspberry".  I believe you can also press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during boot to access the console. Alternatively you could log in via SSH.

This will not work  on OpenELEC.

Comment: use PuTTY to ssh from windows using the IP of the pi (same username/password as above) http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/